# Need Help Syncing Timing of View Loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIView` that is pushed from offscreen to onscreen using the following code. The problem is, the keyboard is being loaded first, then the view, it is like they are two separate views being pushed into the screen.

What I want is for the keyboard and view to load together at the same time.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 
                 animations:^{
                     [self.weightView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [weightTextField becomeFirstResponder];
                 }];
```

Comment: When are you triggering this animation?

Comment: In an IBAction method that is called by a nav button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the `becomeFirstRsponder` in the "animation:" block, not the "completion:" block, so that the keyboard and the view are animated together, and not one after the other.

Comment: It is probably because your animation for the view frame is too short. You can't control the keyboard animation's duration (its animation is done by the OS itself) so you need your view to animate with the same duration if you want them to be synchronous.

Comment: The usual way to sync the animation is to catch the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification (or whatever it's called) and pull the duration out of `notification.userInfo`